# K-means gives non-spherical clusters

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am trying to cluster 24 month utilization behaviors of customers  using sklearn/K-means in python. When I plot the customers by clusters in a 2-D space (Principal Components 1 and 2 of my 24-point values), I see some non-circular shapes too. There are a few points which definitely seem to be closer to another neighboring cluster than the one it has been assigned to. This despite K-means achieving convergence (algorithm stops before reaching max_iter). Can anyone explain if:

1. Non circular clusters can be expected in a 2-D representation of K-means?
2. How to explain examples in the plot where it seems customer should have been assigned to another cluster based on distance even though k-means is converging?

[image: 2D representation of K-means: The two axis are 1st and 2nd principal component of the K-means data and each cluster is a separate clusters]

Comment: 1) If you properly stretch your plot horizontally so that the scale is the same visually you'll find: most of the clusters are roughly circular. 2) You should investigate whether your k-means standardized your data before clustering or not. 3) The strongly vertical dark blue cluster: it could be so peculiarly distributed inside or so peculiarly bordering with the surrounding that K-means indeed formed it as nonspherical _outline_ (one shouldn't take outline very seriously with so many data points); besides, the visible shape of that cluster can be partly misleading due to nontransparent fill.

Comment: Finally, 4) only 2 first PCs of the total 24 dimensions can indeed partly conceal or "distort" the overall more or less spherical shapes. It depends on how much % variance these two PCs explain.

Comment: Thanks @ttnphns I have a few comments/questions about your answer above: 1) I think I need to stretch the plot vertically which would mean non circular clusters will further become elongated.

Comment: 2) I did do standardization of my data. 3) Even if the distribution is peculiar, I wouldn't mathematically expect to find a point which is close to a neighboring cluster center than its own if k-means converges. So my problem is probably not related to that. Can you please explain what you mean by 'non-transparent fill'? 4) First 2 PCs explain 80% variation in my data. Do you think I could still have that much distortion? Thanks again for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nontransparent ink - solid markers used for points on the plot. Try, say, ring as a marker or semi-transparent ink.

Answer (score 1):

1) K-means always forms a [Voronoi partition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) of the space. Thus it is normal that clusters are not circular.
2) K-means is not optimal so yes it is possible to get such final suboptimal partition. You will get different final centroids depending on the position of the initial ones.